# Spring Boot GET function not called in controller

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to validate the reset password inputs using a form. I use Spring Boot with Hibernate and Thymeleaf.

**The issue: HTML form POST function does not call the Spring POST Controller.**
I tried testing this by adding loggers and they would not be called. 
When I enter the new passwords and submit them, the page automatically returns to the Login page.

### HTML:

```
<body class="login login-background">
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main" class="container clear-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <form th:action="@{/resetPassword}"
                          th:object="${resetPasswordForm}" method="POST">
                        <input id="password" type="password"/>
                        <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                               th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I've been trying to find the issue for 2 days but I can't seem to figure it out. I hope somebody can help me out. Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form action url is `/resetPassword` but your controller post url is `/reset`